# Как сделать так что бы коллайдер не реагировал на клик

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть 2 объекта на которых висят два колладера, `A` и `B`. `B` должен реагировать на клики, но его перекрывает `A`. Как сделать так, что `A` не перекрывал `B`?

Comment: Не использовать `OnMouseDown()`.

Comment: А что тогда использовать?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html к примеру. Но там нужно будет перевести ScreenPosition в WorldPosition.

Comment: Хорошо,сейчас посмотю

Comment: Не помогает,так как оно считывает клики вообще по всей сцене а не на обьект

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я помню достаточно разместить коллайдеры в разных слоях и при проверке использовать маску с указанного слоя, чтобы проверить пересечение с конкретным коллайдером.